# New to SQL developer - get "invalid SQL statement" whatever I try to do (ORA:00900)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a view set up where I'm supposed to be able to access the tables, but any query I try to write throws the same error message. Does anyone know what could be wrong, or can someone suggest some next steps for troubleshooting? Is there something I may need to do prior to querying these tables?

[image]

Comment: does this help: http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/03/why-cant-i-see-my-tables-in-oracle-sql-developer/

Comment: what is SHOW TABLES? What do you want to see? All tables? Then `SELECT * from all_tables`

Comment: I'm not sure quite which window you're in there, as it only has a 'run command' button (the green play arrow), and you seem to be somewhere that only expects a single SQL statement. Right-click on the connection you're using and choose 'SQL workseheet'; or get to it from the Tools menu, or Alt-F10. In a worksheet 'show' doesn't error, but just says 'show handled', as it isn't a useful Oracle command.

Comment: There is no "show tables" command in Oracle. See the manual for a complete list of all valid SQL statements: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/toc.htm

Comment: OK, got it still getting used to Oracle. BUt I can't get any select statement to return anything. Ex

Comment: maybe your SQL is bad. can you get SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL; to run and return the today's date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't run a MySQL command like `SHOW TABLES` in Oracle.

`SHOW` is a SQL*Plus command. It lets you see what your session settings are.

`SHOW ALL` or `SHOW PAGESIZE`

You could create a [SQL Code Template](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/11/sql-editor-code-templates-a-must-know-trick/) called `SHOW` or `SHOWTABLE` that you can activate to write the SQL for you, e.g.

```
 select table_name from user_tables order by 1;
```